# typescript + angular: выполнение метода после обновления коллекции

Tags: typescript, websocket, angular, signalr

**Краткая суть**: не могу понять как выполнить метод при получении новых данных через hub (или хотябы просто любое изменение коллекции)
**Подробнее**: есть хаб, в который приходит коллекция данных (ячеек). Этот хаб (файл shot-hub), используется в сервисе, который отрисовывает эти ячейки (файд battlefield-service). Проблема в том, что после обновления надо еще и вызвать метод   для всех ячеек данной коллекции. Коды из хаба и сервиса ниже:

**shot-hub**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder } from '@aspnet/signalr';
import { Cell } from 'src/app/models/cell';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ShotHubService {

  private hub: HubConnection;
  public subject: BehaviorSubject<Cell[]>; //эту коллекцию я планирую передавать (но еще не понимаю с каким типом и как ее передать)

  constructor() {
    this.subject = new BehaviorSubject(Array<Cell>());
    this.hub = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('http://localhost:54708/shothub').build();
    this.hub.start().then(() => console.log('Hub connected'))
    .catch(err => console.error(`Error for hub connection ${err}`));
    this.hub.on('getShots', (cells: Cell[]) => {
      this.subject.next(cells);
    });
   }

   public receiveShots(): Observable<Cell[]> {
     return this.subject.asObservable();
   }
```

**battlefield-service**

```
import { ShotHubService } from './shot-hub.service';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Cell } from 'src/app/models/cell';
import { Ship } from 'src/app/models/ship';
import { CellStatus } from 'src/app/models/cellStatus';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/internal/Subscription';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BattlefieldService {

  shipField: Cell[][];
  ships: Ship[];
  shots: Cell[];
  subscription: Subscription;
  N = 10;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public shotHub: ShotHubService) {
    this.shipField = this.createField();
    this.ships = new Array<Ship>();
    this.shots = shotHub.shotsEnemy; //тут будет присвоено начальное значение коллекции выстрелов, затем по обновлению это коллекции должен (по моей логике) выполняться код метода drawShot для всех элементов

}

  private createField(): Cell[][] {
    let field = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.N; i++) {
      field[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < this.N; j++) {
         field[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, CellStatus.None);
      }
    }
    return field;
  }

  getShipField(): Cell[][] {
    return this.shipField;
  }

  private drawShip(ship: Ship) {
    ship.cells.forEach(cell => {
      this.shipField[cell.y][cell.x].status = cell.status;
    });
  }

  // этот метод должен отрисовать полученные выстрелы
  private drawShot(shot: Cell) {
    this.shipField[shot.y][shot.x].status = shot.status;
  }
 }
```

Comment: подписаться и вызвать метод с пришедшими данными, как аргумент

Comment: @overthesanity для не шарящего: это как?

Comment: подписываешься на `Subject` из своего сервиса в компоненте, в колбеке получишь свои данные, далее вызываешь метод который тебе нужен, который должен их обработать

Comment: @overthesanity, я читал про такое, но все статьи что я прочитал у меня не сработали. я решил выложить код, который не выдает в консоль кучу ошибок. у меня именно сложность в том, КАК подписаться и выполнять.

Comment: дружище, ну почитай чуть чуть туториал по rxjs и все поймешь) подписка делается через `subscribe`, [почитай](https://medium.com/@kosmogradsky/subject-%D0%B2-rxjs-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-c9099231be6d)

Comment: @overthesanity, спасибо, но первую страницу гугла я уже прочитал. чет понятнее не стало

Comment: понимаешь, так же тоже низя лезть в дебри ангуляра не зная основ, это как учить asp дот нет без знания си шарпа)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дам все-таки более развернутый ответ.
С хабом у меня не вышло, но и суть вопроса не про хаб была.
собственно суть
в battlefield-service создаем переменную `subscription: Subscription;`
далее в конструкторе пишем следующий код

```
this.subscription = shotService.enemyShots.subscribe(s => s.forEach(shot => this.drawShot(shot)));
```

Здесь `shotService` сообщает нам о том, какие выстрелы сделал оппонент и затем с помощью `this.drawShot` мы эти выстрелы отрисовываем

Answer (score 0):

В `subsribe`   делаешь еще один `subscribe`:

```
обновления.subscribe(x=>{метод})
```

Comment: День добрый. Можете подробностей в ответ добавить?

Comment: `обновления.subscribe(x=>{метод})`